# Use Data From PHP in JavaScript VIA Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, associative-array

I am learning PDO'S. I have a simple program that retrieves on button click all users in an SQL table and encodes them into JSON. It then returns this data and is retrieved via AJAX. I alert out the data and it is in Array format. I want to know how I can actually access these values, nothing I tried work. The table columns are "name" , "message" and "posted" if that helps.

```
    $("button").click(function(){

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Get/index.php',

            success: function(data) {

            //  var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            //  var v = data.name;
            }
        });



<?php
//print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());

//create handler of new PDO object with parameters of sql
//details, username and password_hash
try {
  $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=app','root','');
  $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {

//die("Sorry Database Issue");

echo $e->getMessage();
die();
}



$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM guestbook ');
query->execute();


$results=query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


// save the JSON encoded array
print json_encode($results);



return $results;
?>
```

Comment: Hi! If the code in your comment belongs to the question, please edit the question and add it there so that it has some formatting to it.

Comment: Sorry no I removed it. The code above is all that is needed. The Ajax request and then the PHP.

Comment: If I alert for example data[0], I get the first character in what is returned. I tried converting using parseJSON on the client side but that didn't work either

Comment: This can have multiple reasons.
First, you do not need the the return line. Then you might want to take a look on [jquery's json functionality](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Additionally, are there any values in the table `guestbook` ?

Comment: I return results down at the last line. Yeah the values are coming back fine, If I alert(data) I get an array with all the correct values in it, but it is as if it's coming back as a string, no matter what way I try access the values individually like alert(data.name) or alert(data[0].name) or so on, nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned & updated the code and added jquery json:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON('Get/index.php', function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( key, entry ) {
            var v = entry.name;
            // and so on
        });
    });
});
<?php
try {
  $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=app','root','');
  $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM guestbook ');
query->execute();
$results=query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// save the JSON encoded array
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Comment: Tried that but nothing happens on button click. Sorry my code was messy I was trying different things and not deleting spaces..

Comment: Are there any values in the table at all? What, if you simply do `die(print_r($results));` ?

Comment: The values in the table are fine, an array is returned with the correct values. If I do my original code and alert(data) it shows the array with the values. Is there a way of adding an image on here? If so I can show you what happens.

Comment: Images: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [message] => Hi there [name] => michael [posted] => 2015-10-01 00:00:00 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [message] => Shut it [name] => tim [posted] => 2015-10-26 00:00:00 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 5 [message] => test [name] => michael [posted] => 2015-10-10 21:06:32 ) )

Comment: That is what is returned to JavaScript which I can alert out with alert(data)